# Change user-agent of javascript audio player

Tags: javascript, streaming, user-agent

I use the following code to play an audio stream on my site and was wondering if how I could change the user-agent so that it appears in the streaming server logs as something other than 'Mozilla 5' for example. Ideally I want to set it to a custom value so that I can identify it in the logs.

I'm assuming that I may need something more custom (a custom developed player) to do this, or would it always display this as ultimately the request is coming from a browser?

```
<script>
    var audio = new Audio("<?php echo $player_stream; ?>");
    $('#play-pause-button, #play-pause-button-small').on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('fa-play')) {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-play');
        $(this).addClass('fa-pause');
        audio.play();
        } else {
        $(this).removeClass('fa-pause');
        $(this).addClass('fa-play');
        audio.pause();
        }
    });

    audio.onended = function() {
    $("#play-pause-button, #play-pause-button-small").removeClass('fa-pause');
    $("#play-pause-button, #play-pause-button-small").addClass('fa-play');
    };

    $(".btn-effect").click(function() {
        $("." + $(this).attr('id')).css("display", "block")
        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try **navigator.userAgent**.
EXAMPLE:

```js
var usr = navigator.userAgent;
```

and send `usr` to the server.

Comment: thank you, I'm not sure I know how to do that, but it gives me a place to start, thanks.

Comment: I' not sure that is what I was looking for. I do not want to detect the user-agent, I want to modify it. Thanks,

Comment: ok, understood. Sadly idk how to do that programatically, but i can do it in dev console.